# sqlite3 shell command : database file not found, but path exists :

Tags: bash, shell, sqlite

The problem is simple:

echo ".tables" | sqlite3 $myPathVariable

If I do: `PATH=/my_path`  it works but i I do `myPathVariable="my_path"` it fails.
The path is retrieved after getting the result of a grep+sed command like myPathVariable=`... grep ... sed`

I need to retrieve dynamically the myPathVariable at execution time, can you please help me to achieve that, I must be missing something basic!

By the way: `echo ".tables" | sqlite3 my_path` works but
`echo ".tables" | sqlite3 "my_path"`

Edit: the variable PATH was just a bad name here, it doesn t refer to the PATH env variable, sorry :) .
Then I noticed that the problem lies within sqlite3: 
The command `.open ~/myDatabaseFilePath` fails.
The command `.open "~/myDatabaseFilePath"` fails.
The command `.open "/.../myDatabaseFilePath"` fails.
But the command `.open /.../myDatabaseFilePath` works.
So sqlite3 can't deal with path containing '~' or surrounded by quotes!

The path generated at execution is correct, the file exists.
It's just a workarround but it doesn't explain why it doesn't work!

I'm just curious to know why the behaviour is not the same ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `PATH` is a [very important shell variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PATH). Don't overwrite it. I'm surprised your shell can find sqlite3. Get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES

Comment: The answer to your question is most likely: given your current directory (`pwd`), is "my_path" the correct *relative* directory?

Comment: Please provide a more realistic example; the literal strings `my_path` and `"my_path"` are *absolutely* identical to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Once you obtain the db name (which by the way is not a path but a filename) by whatever means you are using, check if it exists and is readable.

```
dbname=$(... grep ... sed ... whatever)
if [[ ! -r "$dbname" ]]
then
    echo "$dbname does not exist or is not readable" >&2
    exit 1
fi
sqlite3 "$dbname" .tables
```